# Accessibility properties not updating in loaded swf

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, accessibility

I'm making a modular site, that loads in external swfs that need to have decent screen reader names for each of the buttons.

The shell swf is set up to work with Thunder and NVDA screen readers by creating an  AccessiblityProperties instance and assigning it to the relevent display objects then calling Accessibility.updateProperties( ) ; This method works in the main swf, but when used in the loaded swf it's not picking up the updated accessibility properties of the buttons, even though Accessibiltiyy.updateProperties( ) ; as been called again.

Does anyone have any idea if screen readers are unable to pick up run time loaded swf accesbility properties, or if there is something else I need to do, that I'm not doing.

Cheers!

Comment: Are the *loaded swfs* calling `Accessibility.updateProperties()` from within them selves by chance?

Answer (score 0):

You may be loading your swfs into a different Application Domain or Loader Context. This is usually a good thing to keep loaded code from interfering accidentally with the shell's classes. However, depending on how Accessibility works, the static methods may be being called on two different security contexts.

Take a look here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/LoaderContext.html